# How to validate excel file in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am implementing a file upload service and need a validation for excel file.
my form look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}">
        <table class="content-centered">
           <tr>
              <td><input type="file" file-model="imageToUpload" data-rule-required="true"
                 accept="application/vnd.ms-excel" /></td>
              <td><span ng-class="{errorMessage: fileStatus.status == false,
              regularMessage: fileStatus.status == true}"> &nbsp{{fileStatus.message}}
               </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
           </table>

        <div class="centered" style="margin-top: 12px;">
            <div ng-click='imageUpload()' class="btn blueBtn">Upload &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
            </div>
            <div ng-click='$close()' class="btn orgBtn">Close</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i have used `data-rule-required="true"` and `accept="application/vnd.ms-excel`" for validation.but it didn't work. do you have any idea about how file validation work in angular js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is not inbuilt function for validating excel file in angular or javascript. i have done this using extensions of particular file:

```
$scope.fileToUpload.name='uploadSchoolFeeData.xls';
```

then we can validate it using:

```
    if (($scope.fileToUpload.name.substring($scope.fileToUpload.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) != 'xls') && ($scope.fileToUpload.name.substring($scope.fileToUpload.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) != 'xlsx')) {
$scope.errorMsg='please upload valid excel file';
}
```

using this we can validate all file.